# Loop through records, updating status based on balance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of `accounts` with balances.
I also have a table `items` with a list of items each tagged by an account_id.
Each item has a status which marks the item as either 0 - unpaid and 1 - paid.

I need a query or stored procedure which can go through and do this marking while sorted by date-time

For Instance:I have three items worth $50 each, I pay $120 into an account. After the query/procedure, the first two items should be marked 1 and the last 0

Note:Items can be deleted after being marked as paid and balances can change at any time so I can't just mark items as payments come in. I need a way to do this in a batch mode and just run this query/stored procedure every time a change is made

Comment: what have you tried so far ? and y have u  tagged both `mysql` and `sql-server` ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I've never come across anything like this before. I am unsure of ways to solve this particular problem. So far I have managed to calculate the total balances for each account and how much is owing with regards to the item prices...I put sql-server because I thought perhaps I would need some kind of script running on the server

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (item_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, amount INT NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL,50);
 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL,50);
 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL,50);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +---------+--------+
 | item_id | amount |
 +---------+--------+
 |       1 |     50 |
 |       2 |     50 |
 |       3 |     50 |
 +---------+--------+

 SELECT x.*
      , SUM(y.amount) rt 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.item_id <= x.item_id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.item_id;
 +---------+--------+------+
 | item_id | amount | rt   |
 +---------+--------+------+
 |       1 |     50 |   50 |
 |       2 |     50 |  100 |
 |       3 |     50 |  150 |
 +---------+--------+------+

 SELECT x.*
      , CASE WHEN SUM(y.amount) < 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END paid 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.item_id <= x.item_id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.item_id;
 +---------+--------+------+
 | item_id | amount | paid |
 +---------+--------+------+
 |       1 |     50 |    1 |
 |       2 |     50 |    1 |
 |       3 |     50 |    0 |
 +---------+--------+------+
```

Note, in your case, you may be less interested in evaluationg results that have been 'paid' already.

Comment: No I am interested in results that have been paid but with regards to the number we are using, i.e. 120 is it possible that we take this number from the balance in account and linked by account_id in both situations and can you show me how to update a field call in items rather then just view it?

Comment: Without understanding more about your table structures, I'll leave it to others, more knowledgeable and more inclined, to take up the challenge.